# Problem service worker not in Firefox addon's navigator

Tags: firefox-addon, service-worker

I'm currently building a Firefox addon imported from the Chrome extension I made. This extension require a service worker, which work in Chrome, but it don't in Firefox, when I console.log("serviceWorker" in navigator) in the addon devtool it print false but in Firefox webtool it print yes

I tried changing some option in the about:config but I don't remember which.

Comment: It don't work neither in the others addons btw